# Best corner topology for clean subdivision and shiny materials

Tags: topology

I'm working on a part of a tyre and I think I need some guidance on how structure the topology around sharp corners. When I turn on Blender's "metal car paint" matcap I can see when I move around the object that there are odd shading around the corners (where I will put the threads later). I'm sitting here redoing and redoing but I can never completely remove the weird shading.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flatten your shape and create this kind of topology (move the edges close to each other to sharp the angles):

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface*, then 2 *Simple Deform* modifiers (in *Bend* mode) in order to bend the object on Z and X:

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar the the Simple Deform modifiers, I have to check them out. How would you flatten a shape like this, if you know?

Comment: I've selected your mesh and SY0

Comment: You mean you pressed s+y+0, or what?

Comment: Yes that's it.......

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to model the repeating part flat, then use Array and Mirror modifiers, and 2 Simple Deform modifiers to shape it into the right form. then you only need to make sure there is enough geometry for the deformations to happen nicely. Weighted Normal modifier might also help with shading.

This is more flexible for making changes as well.

[image]